# Special Sorting columns dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have the dataframre below .

```
 d = {'id': ['x1', 'x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7'],'t1': [3,11,4,4,10,16,8],'t2':[20,14,4,15,22,11,4], 
 't3':[14,2,12,18,16,16,11]}
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to do add column that contains the sort on t1 then if for two lines we have t1 equal then we can have a look on t2 and do the same thing.
My column will contain.

```
df['calculated'] =[7,2,6,5,3,1,4]
```

My dataframe expected will be:

```
 d = {'id': ['x1', 'x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7'],'t1': [3,11,4,4,10,16,8],'t2':[20,14,4,15,22,11,4], 
 't3':[14,2,12,18,16,16,11],'calculated':[7,2,6,5,3,1,4]}
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: how do you obtain calculated column? . Is it output that you expect?

Comment: is just the desired output

Comment: you should show your dataframe expected....we need understand what you need

Comment: @anky_91 i updated my original post. Please have a look

Comment: @Miss sure, thanks, can you explain how you get 7 for the first row?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by all columns for test if equal and create new column e.g. by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['t1','t2','t3'], ascending=False).assign(new=range(1, len(df) + 1))
print (df1)
   id  t1  t2  t3  calculated  new
5  x6  16  11  16           1    1
1  x2  11  14   2           2    2
4  x5  10  22  16           3    3
6  x7   8   4  11           4    4
3  x4   4  15  18           5    5
2  x3   4   4  12           6    6
0  x1   3  20  14           7    7
```

Last if necessary original index add [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df1.sort_index()
print (df1)
   id  t1  t2  t3  calculated  new
0  x1   3  20  14           7    7
1  x2  11  14   2           2    2
2  x3   4   4  12           6    6
3  x4   4  15  18           5    5
4  x5  10  22  16           3    3
5  x6  16  11  16           1    1
6  x7   8   4  11           4    4
```

Comment: @anky_91 - I hope so, I understand it if duplicated values in `t1` then sort them by `t2` (only duplicates) and same for `t3` what get if sorting by all columns.

Comment: Thank youu . @ jezrael can you please explain more your solution?

Comment: @Miss - It is like sort values working for more columns - first sorting by `t1`. there are duplicates for `4` values, so sorting for `t2` is only for this rows with `4`. Then for group with `4` are not duplicates for `t2`, so not sorting by `t3`.